# Should an elastic-net always outperform lasso?

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

Since the lasso is a subset of the elastic-net, shouldn't a continuous grid of the ridge and lasso paramaters in the elastic-net always outperform the lasso regression?